# Host projects safely on linux server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, php, web-hosting

I'd like to host php projects and perhaps asp.net prjs on my server. Theres two main issues i have.

1) The php files scanning my filesystem. I dont want it to visit /var/www/majorapp/config.xml and read the db or admin password. Along with source of other host projects (which are also in php)

2) track or kill processes that eat up CPU or ram. If a php file or project is doing something cpu intensive i'd like to kill it. It would be great if it works on spawn process as well.

bonus: if i can prevent it from using the network such as visiting http://some_site_user_is_ip_banned_at.com or http://myself.com/project/me/recurseMe

I am considering allowing the user run asp.net prjs as well since my site is using asp.net. My server is apache2 on a linode virtual host. Debian lenny

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use something like Linux Containers (LXC) to provide isolated environments to each project.  This solution lets you assign hard limits to things like memory and CPU utilization, and it lets you set network firewalls and so forth for each project.  This also means each project gets its own filesystem namespace.  More information here:

- http://lxc.sourceforge.net/

Similar projects include:

- Linux Vserver: http://linux-vserver.org/Welcome_to_Linux-VServer.org